# How to save folder state so that I can monitor changes in it

Tags: files, directory, sync, log, monitoring

I have a folder with 5000 ~10mb files, I need something that would save something like list of all files and preferably their hashes so that it can track file changes/renames, and then later compare the folder to the saved state and show all differences. Basically something to keep a history of everything that happened in a folder.

Now resilio sync kinda does that, it has a folder history option, and it also seems to watch the folder continuously rather than scanning on demand, but it doesn't work without me syncing the folder with something, and I would rather not have something run constantly in the background. Although megasync on windows and android seems to use very little resources while it basically does the same thing except it compares files with cloud versions, and if the app is as easy on resources, I'd be fine with it,

Comment: Is something as simple as doing `ls -l` of the folder to some file and then later comparing the saved output with the current output of `ls -l` enough for your needs?

Comment: @raj thank you.  The files get renamed quite a lot as well so I would prefer something that creates hashes. I guess since it logs file sizes I could make something that would track renames based on size but I think there is something like a 0.1% chance two files will have same size.